# Subplots do not align properly when using matlab2tikz

Tags: align, matlab2tikz

I am experiencing some problems with matlab2tikz. I create a subplot in matlab. however, when I convert it to .tex code using matlab2tikz, the subplots are not properly aligned.

[image: Subplots]

Code:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.3.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2013, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\setlength\figureheight{2.5cm} %18
\setlength\figurewidth{3.5cm}  %13

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.00501089889010359,
ymax=-1.10818730174322e-06,
name=plot5,
title={$\mathbf{h}_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 -0.00345456702655381 \\
2 -0.000675903386340118 \\
3 -0.000130410954524901 \\
4 -2.94450659967388e-05 \\
5 -1.03071106894309e-05 \\
6 -5.35205604543232e-06 \\
7 -2.88263281908452e-06 \\
8 -1.79003699735114e-06 \\
9 -1.50817003408132e-06 \\
10 -1.10818730174322e-06 \\
10 -5.04991723039583e-06 \\
9 -6.66218464581703e-06 \\
8 -8.63006682245981e-06 \\
7 -1.24166716857776e-05 \\
6 -2.05317904630048e-05 \\
5 -4.2203235333424e-05 \\
4 -0.000113855460995738 \\
3 -0.000383066364441076 \\
2 -0.00137698350977568 \\
1 -0.00501089889010359 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00431548260794615\\
2 -0.00104147156809573\\
3 -0.000264479995269745\\
4 -7.51947217807023e-05\\
5 -2.6660363866575e-05\\
6 -1.27637467209594e-05\\
7 -7.82754645280169e-06\\
8 -5.47227219023505e-06\\
9 -4.03414319411687e-06\\
10 -3.03154539164935e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00345456702655381\\
2 -0.000675903386340118\\
3 -0.000130410954524901\\
4 -2.94450659967388e-05\\
5 -1.03071106894309e-05\\
6 -5.35205604543232e-06\\
7 -2.88263281908452e-06\\
8 -1.79003699735114e-06\\
9 -1.50817003408132e-06\\
10 -1.10818730174322e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00501089889010359\\
2 -0.00137698350977568\\
3 -0.000383066364441076\\
4 -0.000113855460995738\\
5 -4.2203235333424e-05\\
6 -2.05317904630048e-05\\
7 -1.24166716857776e-05\\
8 -8.63006682245981e-06\\
9 -6.66218464581703e-06\\
10 -5.04991723039583e-06\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.00225758080163731,
ymax=-2.8655550332133e-06,
name=plot2,
at=(plot5.above north west),
anchor=below south west,
title={$\Pi_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 -0.00172504637488861 \\
2 -0.000397437737564947 \\
3 -0.000103077174851604 \\
4 -3.87282043958605e-05 \\
5 -1.94624813719727e-05 \\
6 -1.13025526805258e-05 \\
7 -7.38695452721407e-06 \\
8 -5.43190337794815e-06 \\
9 -4.02675292668006e-06 \\
10 -2.8655550332133e-06 \\
10 -7.37937702766436e-06 \\
9 -9.89985344732915e-06 \\
8 -1.2993171600543e-05 \\
7 -1.71192136150357e-05 \\
6 -2.35190919019058e-05 \\
5 -3.62070899687711e-05 \\
4 -7.0468907422629e-05 \\
3 -0.000189191062542433 \\
2 -0.000604673691699618 \\
1 -0.00225758080163731 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00201894482014313\\
2 -0.000507719905591277\\
3 -0.000146346883483665\\
4 -5.45388936928148e-05\\
5 -2.78193061768407e-05\\
6 -1.78089813281687e-05\\
7 -1.27018841810939e-05\\
8 -9.4381582756386e-06\\
9 -7.11367226108434e-06\\
10 -5.38789645570094e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00172504637488861\\
2 -0.000397437737564947\\
3 -0.000103077174851604\\
4 -3.87282043958605e-05\\
5 -1.94624813719727e-05\\
6 -1.13025526805258e-05\\
7 -7.38695452721407e-06\\
8 -5.43190337794815e-06\\
9 -4.02675292668006e-06\\
10 -2.8655550332133e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00225758080163731\\
2 -0.000604673691699618\\
3 -0.000189191062542433\\
4 -7.0468907422629e-05\\
5 -3.62070899687711e-05\\
6 -2.35190919019058e-05\\
7 -1.71192136150357e-05\\
8 -1.2993171600543e-05\\
9 -9.89985344732915e-06\\
10 -7.37937702766436e-06\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.00209719194684382,
ymax=-2.20966126396327e-06,
name=plot1,
at=(plot2.left of south west),
anchor=right of south east,
title={$y_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 -0.00146497452822018 \\
2 -0.000288649279264572 \\
3 -6.22023182713718e-05 \\
4 -2.13430751836788e-05 \\
5 -1.1891895720248e-05 \\
6 -7.95117840333981e-06 \\
7 -5.3639292215274e-06 \\
8 -3.92489059230366e-06 \\
9 -2.93879098969135e-06 \\
10 -2.20966126396327e-06 \\
10 -4.24082730576814e-06 \\
9 -5.59529415668225e-06 \\
8 -7.44917596538774e-06 \\
7 -1.0139110505715e-05 \\
6 -1.4864454172446e-05 \\
5 -2.59443702201462e-05 \\
4 -5.72727615147997e-05 \\
3 -0.000166404643039401 \\
2 -0.000575905629749844 \\
1 -0.00209719194684382 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00177322047436181\\
2 -0.000441012302646872\\
3 -0.000121354133221837\\
4 -4.11769052260563e-05\\
5 -1.89114056616308e-05\\
6 -1.13182499774292e-05\\
7 -7.83237094477331e-06\\
8 -5.75203615564292e-06\\
9 -4.31568314500144e-06\\
10 -3.26217474268581e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00146497452822018\\
2 -0.000288649279264572\\
3 -6.22023182713718e-05\\
4 -2.13430751836788e-05\\
5 -1.1891895720248e-05\\
6 -7.95117840333981e-06\\
7 -5.3639292215274e-06\\
8 -3.92489059230366e-06\\
9 -2.93879098969135e-06\\
10 -2.20966126396327e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00209719194684382\\
2 -0.000575905629749844\\
3 -0.000166404643039401\\
4 -5.72727615147997e-05\\
5 -2.59443702201462e-05\\
6 -1.4864454172446e-05\\
7 -1.0139110505715e-05\\
8 -7.44917596538774e-06\\
9 -5.59529415668225e-06\\
10 -4.24082730576814e-06\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.00168097377449383,
ymax=-3.10523076703095e-05,
name=plot4,
at=(plot1.below south west),
anchor=above north west,
title={$gini_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 -0.00115269931362899 \\
2 -0.000414357529291476 \\
3 -0.000241052105818484 \\
4 -0.000166483609572832 \\
5 -0.000122324390085082 \\
6 -9.27323872551011e-05 \\
7 -7.13321536600087e-05 \\
8 -5.46610057539643e-05 \\
9 -4.17178769100413e-05 \\
10 -3.10523076703095e-05 \\
10 -4.92795799808543e-05 \\
9 -6.53563473110852e-05 \\
8 -8.59139726217539e-05 \\
7 -0.00011303551004993 \\
6 -0.000148417639142195 \\
5 -0.00019942768407738 \\
4 -0.000277807586485712 \\
3 -0.000418003461167327 \\
2 -0.000721529803204446 \\
1 -0.00168097377449383 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.0014021134184268\\
2 -0.000584961510358214\\
3 -0.000330966757812961\\
4 -0.00022415311995061\\
5 -0.000163509532495376\\
6 -0.000122426892817607\\
7 -9.24720671450618e-05\\
8 -7.00529463311063e-05\\
9 -5.31247738989645e-05\\
10 -4.03041778549794e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00115269931362899\\
2 -0.000414357529291476\\
3 -0.000241052105818484\\
4 -0.000166483609572832\\
5 -0.000122324390085082\\
6 -9.27323872551011e-05\\
7 -7.13321536600087e-05\\
8 -5.46610057539643e-05\\
9 -4.17178769100413e-05\\
10 -3.10523076703095e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00168097377449383\\
2 -0.000721529803204446\\
3 -0.000418003461167327\\
4 -0.000277807586485712\\
5 -0.00019942768407738\\
6 -0.000148417639142195\\
7 -0.00011303551004993\\
8 -8.59139726217539e-05\\
9 -6.53563473110852e-05\\
10 -4.92795799808543e-05\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.00603922755533445,
ymax=-2.27238902143767e-06,
name=plot7,
at=(plot4.below south west),
anchor=above north west,
title={$\tau_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 -0.00416259987248788 \\
2 -0.000821490438826761 \\
3 -0.000162872421946625 \\
4 -3.69847546559526e-05 \\
5 -1.53756716312764e-05 \\
6 -1.01306490969816e-05 \\
7 -5.96305319115753e-06 \\
8 -3.97921661084155e-06 \\
9 -3.01738894031844e-06 \\
10 -2.27238902143767e-06 \\
10 -6.92359772856699e-06 \\
9 -9.13661539977961e-06 \\
8 -1.20765035259568e-05 \\
7 -1.71335508190595e-05 \\
6 -2.82828381782396e-05 \\
5 -5.31584314371197e-05 \\
4 -0.000141012427023773 \\
3 -0.000467770705638956 \\
2 -0.00166658033180311 \\
1 -0.00603922755533445 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00520209284512705\\
2 -0.00126197771941917\\
3 -0.000325157061880664\\
4 -9.57831743937306e-05\\
5 -3.61160666973903e-05\\
6 -1.84228717096736e-05\\
7 -1.17437319251879e-05\\
8 -8.34829026805681e-06\\
9 -6.19198476661781e-06\\
10 -4.66263276299203e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00416259987248788\\
2 -0.000821490438826761\\
3 -0.000162872421946625\\
4 -3.69847546559526e-05\\
5 -1.53756716312764e-05\\
6 -1.01306490969816e-05\\
7 -5.96305319115753e-06\\
8 -3.97921661084155e-06\\
9 -3.01738894031844e-06\\
10 -2.27238902143767e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.00603922755533445\\
2 -0.00166658033180311\\
3 -0.000467770705638956\\
4 -0.000141012427023773\\
5 -5.31584314371197e-05\\
6 -2.82828381782396e-05\\
7 -1.71335508190595e-05\\
8 -1.20765035259568e-05\\
9 -9.13661539977961e-06\\
10 -6.92359772856699e-06\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=1.80097178158201e-06,
ymax=0.00511916915896521,
name=plot8,
at=(plot7.right of south east),
anchor=left of south west,
title={$mc_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 0.00511916915896521 \\
2 0.00136204215187627 \\
3 0.000376211912825039 \\
4 0.000115638097918411 \\
5 4.27282084548841e-05 \\
6 2.25536894293971e-05 \\
7 1.33187476510782e-05 \\
8 9.74034692285963e-06 \\
9 7.13920733477758e-06 \\
10 5.56385970423845e-06 \\
10 1.80097178158201e-06 \\
9 2.22083506269677e-06 \\
8 3.17693110112038e-06 \\
7 4.46834640963067e-06 \\
6 8.04152059710739e-06 \\
5 1.22551607039528e-05 \\
4 3.27626825081945e-05 \\
3 0.000130474838870909 \\
2 0.000687024008969819 \\
1 0.00364157489427699 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.00430182236159583\\
2 0.00104142110424126\\
3 0.000267322828456688\\
4 7.81715123203169e-05\\
5 2.91487111352555e-05\\
6 1.47155023760642e-05\\
7 9.32596783430134e-06\\
8 6.61398353030376e-06\\
9 4.90173057574167e-06\\
10 3.69021990376062e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.00511916915896521\\
2 0.00136204215187627\\
3 0.000376211912825039\\
4 0.000115638097918411\\
5 4.27282084548841e-05\\
6 2.25536894293971e-05\\
7 1.33187476510782e-05\\
8 9.74034692285963e-06\\
9 7.13920733477758e-06\\
10 5.56385970423845e-06\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.00364157489427699\\
2 0.000687024008969819\\
3 0.000130474838870909\\
4 3.27626825081945e-05\\
5 1.22551607039528e-05\\
6 8.04152059710739e-06\\
7 4.46834640963067e-06\\
8 3.17693110112038e-06\\
9 2.22083506269677e-06\\
10 1.80097178158201e-06\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=2.60813804087712e-05,
ymax=0.000303658089562064,
name=plot9,
at=(plot8.right of south east),
anchor=left of south west,
title={$\xi_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 0.000222790628730096 \\
2 0.000303658089562064 \\
3 0.000260350186140512 \\
4 0.000210118006188031 \\
5 0.00016079353035181 \\
6 0.000122987468878899 \\
7 9.21759063873817e-05 \\
8 6.99110059263486e-05 \\
9 5.34231432694487e-05 \\
10 4.08290855268278e-05 \\
10 2.60813804087712e-05 \\
9 3.39528929677035e-05 \\
8 4.41813661145596e-05 \\
7 5.82551616998273e-05 \\
6 7.88385323661212e-05 \\
5 0.000102268414125695 \\
4 0.000134272769322263 \\
3 0.000165708636108153 \\
2 0.000201693053864083 \\
1 0.000141358860472174 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000186618989669907\\
2 0.000253425284749385\\
3 0.000217645810459036\\
4 0.00017117238533699\\
5 0.000131305133139587\\
6 9.99539260839012e-05\\
7 7.59064959475604e-05\\
8 5.76033890037442e-05\\
9 4.37063306244968e-05\\
10 3.31624231705872e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000222790628730096\\
2 0.000303658089562064\\
3 0.000260350186140512\\
4 0.000210118006188031\\
5 0.00016079353035181\\
6 0.000122987468878899\\
7 9.21759063873817e-05\\
8 6.99110059263486e-05\\
9 5.34231432694487e-05\\
10 4.08290855268278e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000141358860472174\\
2 0.000201693053864083\\
3 0.000165708636108153\\
4 0.000134272769322263\\
5 0.000102268414125695\\
6 7.88385323661212e-05\\
7 5.82551616998273e-05\\
8 4.41813661145596e-05\\
9 3.39528929677035e-05\\
10 2.60813804087712e-05\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=1.7998086123544e-07,
ymax=0.000334211220229877,
name=plot6,
at=(plot9.above north west),
anchor=below south west,
title={$w_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 0.000334211220229877 \\
2 9.14465986731755e-05 \\
3 2.57731001454126e-05 \\
4 8.18664868598024e-06 \\
5 3.36427666235845e-06 \\
6 1.70211077388238e-06 \\
7 1.11948708599735e-06 \\
8 7.93570305537838e-07 \\
9 5.98765661545542e-07 \\
10 4.47057854242872e-07 \\
10 1.7998086123544e-07 \\
9 2.45472235073374e-07 \\
8 3.24401496817894e-07 \\
7 4.63396325305065e-07 \\
6 6.66827528410241e-07 \\
5 1.22993609662919e-06 \\
4 2.48457431730603e-06 \\
3 8.70642404696836e-06 \\
2 4.2232347571565e-05 \\
1 0.000213313384183331 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000276986083131615\\
2 6.7698203194526e-05\\
3 1.77667593525434e-05\\
4 5.45320186301583e-06\\
5 2.19107707579153e-06\\
6 1.18362417373849e-06\\
7 7.78567336054657e-07\\
8 5.60452993803536e-07\\
9 4.17432676540729e-07\\
10 3.14670057797263e-07\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000334211220229877\\
2 9.14465986731755e-05\\
3 2.57731001454126e-05\\
4 8.18664868598024e-06\\
5 3.36427666235845e-06\\
6 1.70211077388238e-06\\
7 1.11948708599735e-06\\
8 7.93570305537838e-07\\
9 5.98765661545542e-07\\
10 4.47057854242872e-07\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000213313384183331\\
2 4.2232347571565e-05\\
3 8.70642404696836e-06\\
4 2.48457431730603e-06\\
5 1.22993609662919e-06\\
6 6.66827528410241e-07\\
7 4.63396325305065e-07\\
8 3.24401496817894e-07\\
9 2.45472235073374e-07\\
10 1.7998086123544e-07\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymin=-0.000164836636459609,
ymax=0.000966501505072489,
at=(plot6.above north west),
anchor=below south west,
title={$R_t$}
]

\addplot[solid,fill=black,opacity=2.000000e-01,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
1 0.000966501505072489 \\
2 4.10572286161683e-05 \\
3 -0.000112542026187008 \\
4 -0.000114322871182618 \\
5 -9.04979708857556e-05 \\
6 -7.01244029849418e-05 \\
7 -5.34264538939837e-05 \\
8 -3.97266411618843e-05 \\
9 -2.99722739271029e-05 \\
10 -2.31550246172791e-05 \\
10 -3.55346751505243e-05 \\
9 -4.60903350858518e-05 \\
8 -6.07118143305038e-05 \\
7 -8.0872854180708e-05 \\
6 -0.000105087798950864 \\
5 -0.000134402971798932 \\
4 -0.000164836636459609 \\
3 -0.000160067966395918 \\
2 -2.4540253359415e-05 \\
1 0.000648031872134341 \\
};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000806265090133046\\
2 5.60600181431083e-06\\
3 -0.000137162707210898\\
4 -0.000137545531787676\\
5 -0.000112374777083149\\
6 -8.71902972936106e-05\\
7 -6.66134812449333e-05\\
8 -5.06469754696103e-05\\
9 -3.84493039109602e-05\\
10 -2.91766638038332e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000966501505072489\\
2 4.10572286161683e-05\\
3 -0.000112542026187008\\
4 -0.000114322871182618\\
5 -9.04979708857556e-05\\
6 -7.01244029849418e-05\\
7 -5.34264538939837e-05\\
8 -3.97266411618843e-05\\
9 -2.99722739271029e-05\\
10 -2.31550246172791e-05\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.000648031872134341\\
2 -2.4540253359415e-05\\
3 -0.000160067966395918\\
4 -0.000164836636459609\\
5 -0.000134402971798932\\
6 -0.000105087798950864\\
7 -8.0872854180708e-05\\
8 -6.07118143305038e-05\\
9 -4.60903350858518e-05\\
10 -3.55346751505243e-05\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I could fix the alignment of the y axes when adding

```
\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
```

to the preamble. However, the x axis of the w_t plot is still not properly aligned. How could I fix this? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
\pgfplotsset{
  yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right},
  every axis title/.append style={text height=2ex},
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.style={extra description/.code={\path (-.2,1.4);}}]
```

This add an alignment point slightly above and to the left of each plot.

[image: alighned graphs]